# Query with $all and $regex failing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a MongoDB instance that I want to search by checking that a number of regexes are simultaneously satisfied. The query works when I use the $all with /a/, or if I just use the $regex syntax, but not when I use both:

```
> db.claims.findOne({'tags': {$all: [/a/]}}, {description: 1, tags: 1})
{ "_id" : ..., "description" : "Test claim", "tags" : [ "general", "foobar" ] }
> db.claims.find({'tags': {$regex: 'a'}}, {description: 1, tags: 1})
{ "_id" : ..., "description" : "Test claim", "tags" : [ "general", "foobar" ] }
> db.claims.find({'tags': {$all: [{'$regex': 'a'}]}}, {description: 1, tags: 1})
>
```

What's going on? Is there a bug when these two are used together?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, using `$and` should do the trick.

```
db.claims.find({"$and" : [{"tags":{ $regex : 'a'}},{"tags":{ $regex : 'a'}}]}, {description: 1, tags: 1})
```

If only one regex needs to be satisfied use $or. Of course you can mix-and-match `$or` and `$and`.